# Undefined index and '%20' in link

Tags: php

im creating a website for a school project.
I have a form with an action that i generate using php code

```
$qu = "SELECT * FROM u_ where id='$edit_record'";
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$qu);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
$edit_id=$row[0];
$s_roll=$row[1];
}?>
<form method="post" action ="edit.php?edit_form =<?=$edit_id;?">
```

But for some reason my edit page ends up looking like localhost/student/edit_form%20=5 and there is a php error that says undefined edit_form, where does that %20 come from and why does it say undefined index? please help i've been stuck for nearly 2 hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%20 represents a space in an encoded URL, which means that you're passing a space in your link. simply remove the space before the '=' in your last line so that you end up with :

```
<form method="post" action ="edit.php?edit_form=<?=$edit_id;?">
```

Comment: Thank you yes this fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

There's a whitespace after `=`, this should fix it:

```
<form method="post" action ="edit.php?edit_form=<?=$edit_id;?">
```

Comment: @JamesCostigan Please mark the answer that answers your question best as solution.

Comment: Please don't ask for a "Mark my answer as correct". Go for the neutral "Please mark the answer that answers your question best as solution" :)

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is a URL safe space character . You have accidentally left in a space in your string just after `edit_form`.

```
...edit.php?edit_form =<?=$edit_id
                  ---^
```

Comment: Thank you i feel so stupid now